# Puppet Enterprise installation error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: postgresql, puppet, puppet-enterprise

OS version: Ubuntu 12.04

While trying to install puppet enterprise in Ubuntu 12.04, I am getting the below error

```
[Error]: Could not start Service[postgresqld]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/pe-postgresql start' returned 7: Starting pe-postgresql service:  * Sta$
^[[1;31m2016-09-04 15:01:33,752 - [Error]: /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Service[postgresqld]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service$
^[[m2016-09-04 15:01:33,754 -
```

Some more logs:

> 2016-09-04 15:44:35,185 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Master/File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/pe_build]/owner:
>   owner changed 'root' to 'pe-puppet' 2016-09-04 15:44:35,185 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Master/File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/pe_build]/group:
>   group changed 'root' to 'pe-puppet' 2016-09-04 15:45:11,740 - [Error]:
>   Could not start Service[postgresqld]: Execution of
>   '/etc/init.d/pe-postgresql start' returned 7: Starting pe-postgresql
>   service:  * Starting pe-postgresql service: 2016-09-04 15:45:11,741 -
>   [Error]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Service[postgresqld]/ensure:
>   change from stopped to running failed: Could not start
>   Service[postgresqld]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/pe-postgresql start'
>   returned 7: Starting pe-postgresql service:  * Starting pe-postgresql
>   service: 2016-09-04 15:45:11,743 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Pe_postgresql::Validate_db_connection[validate_service_is_running]/Exec[validate
>   postgres connection for /pe-postgres]: Dependency Service[postgresqld]
>   has failures: true 2016-09-04 15:45:11,744 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Pe_postgresql::Validate_db_connection[validate_service_is_running]/Exec[validate
>   postgres connection for /pe-postgres]: Skipping because of failed
>   dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,745 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::service::end]:
>   Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures: true 2016-09-04
>   15:45:11,745 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Service/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::service::end]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,747 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Contrib/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::contrib::end]:
>   Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures: true 2016-09-04
>   15:45:11,747 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Contrib/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::contrib::end]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,748 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Reload/Exec[postgresql_reload]:
>   Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures: true 2016-09-04
>   15:45:11,748 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Reload/Exec[postgresql_reload]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,749 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::end]:
>   Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures: true 2016-09-04
>   15:45:11,750 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Pe_postgresql::Server/Pe_anchor[pe_postgresql::server::end]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,752 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Tablespace[pe-puppetdb]/File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/postgresql/puppetdb]:
>   Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures: true 2016-09-04
>   15:45:11,752 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Tablespace[pe-puppetdb]/File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/postgresql/puppetdb]:
>   Skipping because of failed dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,753 -
>   [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Tablespace[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-puppetdb']: Dependency Service[postgresqld] has
>   failures: true 2016-09-04 15:45:11,753 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Tablespace[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[Create tablespace 'pe-puppetdb']: Skipping because of failed dependencies
>   2016-09-04 15:45:11,754 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE
>   ROLE "pe-puppetdb"  LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER 
>   CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Dependency Service[postgresqld] has failures:
>   true 2016-09-04 15:45:11,755 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[CREATE
>   ROLE "pe-puppetdb"  LOGIN NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOSUPERUSER 
>   CONNECTION LIMIT -1]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
>   2016-09-04 15:45:11,756 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER
>   ROLE "pe-puppetdb" NOSUPERUSER]: Dependency Service[postgresqld] has
>   failures: true 2016-09-04 15:45:11,756 - [Warning]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER
>   ROLE "pe-puppetdb" NOSUPERUSER]: Skipping because of failed
>   dependencies 2016-09-04 15:45:11,757 - [Notice]:
>   /Stage[main]/Puppet_enterprise::Profile::Database/Puppet_enterprise::App_database[puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql::Server::Role[pe-puppetdb]/Pe_postgresql_psql[ALTER
>   ROLE "pe-puppetdb" NOCREATEDB]: Dependency Service[postgresqld] has
>   failures: true

Including this one:

```
 [Error]: Failed to apply catalog: Connection refused - connect(2) for "domain.com" port 4433
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Now postgresql issues are resolved, but still 4433 error is there

```
2016-09-04 16:55:32,314 - [Debug]: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]/owner: owner changed 'pe-puppet' to 'puppet'
2016-09-04 16:55:32,315 - [Debug]: /File[/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]/group: group changed 'pe-puppet' to 'puppet'
2016-09-04 16:55:32,316 - [Debug]: Finishing transaction 72625460
2016-09-04 16:55:32,318 - [Debug]: Creating new connection for https://domain.com:4433
2016-09-04 16:55:32,319 - [Debug]: Starting connection for https://domain.com:4433
2016-09-04 16:55:32,319 - [Debug]: Storing state
2016-09-04 16:55:32,320 - [Info]: Creating state file /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/state.yaml
2016-09-04 16:55:32,437 - [Debug]: Stored state in 0.12 seconds
2016-09-04 16:55:32,477 - [Error]: Failed to apply catalog: Connection refused - connect(2) for "domain.com" port 4433
2016-09-04 16:55:32,495 - [Debug]: Applying settings catalog for sections reporting, metrics
2016-09-04 16:55:32,498 - [Debug]: Finishing transaction 71218160
2016-09-04 16:55:32,498 - [Debug]: Received report to process from domain.com
2016-09-04 16:55:32,531 - [Debug]: Processing report from domain.com with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
* /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet enterprise configure --debug --detailed-exitcodes --modulepath /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/enterprise/modules
* returned: 1
2016-09-04 16:55:38,204 Running command: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent --enable
```

Comment: The error says that you can't connect on port 4433 to domain.com. Is the port 4433 open, do you have a firewall ?  Is there any app listening on that port? Have you tried 'curl -v domain.com:4433' what does it say?

Comment: No Michal, it was opened and I am very sure about that. I have firewll setting, but I opened it already before installing puppetmaster, anyway I switched to Foreman and its working fine now